# Why does this nib stretch horizontally?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios7, xcode5, autolayout

I have recently converted a nib to `autolayout`.  Every aspect of these buttons is fixed: sizes, and distances to dead center of the device.  I was expecting it to be unchanged on the iPad when rotating the orientation, but it is not - the first image below is Portrait, the second Landscape.  What things should I investigate to keep it from stretching horizontally?  Actually, I think it would probably stretch both directions, except that the x dimension in Portrait is the same as the y dimension in Landscape so there is no room to stretch that way.  I looked at Simulated Metrics - View Mode - and it is set to `UIContentModeCenter` which from the description should not allow stretching, but changing this setting has no effect (I get the same result if it is set to `UIContentModeScaleToFill` so I think this is off track).  I must have a flag/toggle wrong somewhere.  EDIT: these are views from the simulator.

[image: Portrait] [image: Land]

Comment: You should explain your constraints in more detail. At a guess, you have constraints from the buttons to the superview edges as well as to each other (or the superview center?). This is forcing the stretching by increasing the size of the buttons. Basically, the required constraints override the content hugging priorities of the buttons, so the buttons no longer hug their content tightly. (If you were to increase the content hugging priority, you'd probably cause conflicts, which might be easier to debug.)

Comment: Could you post a picture of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Sorry to be a bit unclear.  I want the set of buttons to look identical in both orientations, and to look like the left picture above.  The constraints are the middle row/column is centered, and each button is 15 points from its neighbors, and each button is 80 x 80 points.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think you’re saying that you want the blocks to stretch but keep the distances between them the same? If that’s the case, set it up like this:</s>

- inter-item distance constraints that keep the distances between items and the distances from the items to the edges at some constant value.
- constraints that make all the items' widths equal to each other (easiest way to do this is to have every item's width equal a single item's width).
- ditto for heights

**Update:** based on your updated description, here are the constraints you should use:

- all cells' sizes constrained to a fixed size.
- inter-cell spacing constrained to a fixed size.
- center cell (`5 JKL`) constrained to center horizontally and vertically in container
- either no constraints from the edge cells to the edge of the container, or a `>=` spacing constraint, so the distance from the edge cells to the container can vary.

Comment: I don't want anything to stretch or move.  I think those pics above are to scale, it is the interbutton space that stretched. I have the inter-item constraints you suggest, but the buttons' height/width are not constrained to equal each other, the size of the buttons are fixed at 80 x 80 points.  There are no complaints from `autolayout`.

Comment: I think I have what you describe, on the last bullet, I have no constraints to the edges.  Let me review again, maybe I missed one.

Comment: I have buttons 2, 5, 8 centered horizontally in container, and buttons 4, 5, 6 centered vertically in the container.  I suppose centering 2, 8, 4, 6 might be considered unnecessary given that all sizes and spacings are also given.  Do you think this will matter?

Comment: It shouldn’t. Are there any constraints from any of the views’ edges to the container? Would it be possible to post your code or xib?

Comment: I can post the nib, like to a gist, should I export as an xml or what makes sense in this situation (sorry, this is not my normal workflow).

Comment: If it’s a xib/nib, just open it in a text editor and paste its text into gist. Or upload the file to [Cloud app](http://www.getcloudapp.com).

Comment: It's [here](https://gist.github.com/bryanhanson/9d775abfba90ef2aac36)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59615/discussion-between-zev-eisenberg-and-bryan-hanson).